# Einstein's 1905 "Concerning an Heuristic...emission and transformation of light"

Tags: waves, photons, thermal-radiation, wave-particle-duality, photoelectric-effect

I'm currently attempting to read Einstein's annus mirabilis papers, starting with his introduction of the quantization of light in the paper: "Concerning an Heuristic Points of View Toward the Emission and Transformation of Light", which can be found [here](http://www.esfm2005.ipn.mx/ESFM_Images/paper1.pdf).

I was wondering if anyone a few levels above myself could explain sections 1 and 2 for me...? I'm really struggling to understand these sections as I am a bit of a layman on reading papers that are 100+ years old.

Any brief description of what Einstein is saying for these two sections would be fantastic and certainly help me understand this a lot better.

In my words I think obviously in section 1 he is talking about blackbody radiation, but the title of the section elludes to a "difficulty" but I can't quite extract that from the section...? I must be missing something...

Section 2 I feel that Einstein is concluding that the Maxwellian theory is perfectly valid for large wavelengths and large radiation densities breaks down for small wavelengths and small radiation densities? Is that correct?

Like I say, I have spent the best part of two to three days trying to wrap my brain around these two sections but I'm not confident in my own interpretation. If anyone could add to my interpretation or correct it would be excellent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In section 1 he's talking about the [ultraviolet catastrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_catastrophe). Re what you said about section 2, yes. The ultraviolet catastrophe *"is the error at short wavelengths in the Rayleigh–Jeans law (depicted as 'classical theory' in the graph) for the energy emitted by an ideal black-body".*

[image]

<sub>Public domain image by Darth Kule, see [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Black_body.svg)</sub>